# Group of check box and one hidden text field jQuery validation not working for group of checkbox as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm currently working on jQuery validation for a group of check boxes. With my current code, if the user clicks the next button an error message will show  **You have missed 6 fields. Please fill the highlighted field before submit.** If the user clicks any of the check boxes the error message should go away.

Here is my current jQuery code:

```
$.validator.addClassRules("chk_Field_hlt", {
    require_from_group: [1, ".chk_Field_hlt"]
});
```

With this I am trying to group all the checkboxes and if any of them are selected the rest of the errRed classes should go away and validation shouldn't happen for these checkboxes.

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/e7Lcs1nm/)

any suggestion people

Comment: So, do you just want to check for at least one box filled out?

Comment: @Cory yes this is what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make ONE checkbox required out of a group of checkboxes, you simply need the same `name` on all the checkboxes in the group.  When the `required` rule is used, it's satisfied when one checkbox from this group is clicked.

You do not need to create a custom class called `required_Field` applied with the `.rules()` method.  All of that is superfluous.  Simply change the class to `required` and the plugin will automatically apply the `required` rule.

Then your highlight and unhighlight needed to be adjusted slightly to pick up all checkboxes in the group.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/e7Lcs1nm/4/**

Comment: thanks for the help but still it shows after selecting one checkbox  

You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted

Comment: @Mahadevan, I thought you had TWO groups of checkboxes.  No?  Then easy fix.  http://jsfiddle.net/e7Lcs1nm/4/

Comment: hey super  awesome @Sparky again you rocked let me try in my project code 
i have one more question can you please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736730/how-to-validate-a-decimal-value-input/33736918?noredirect=1#comment55244227_33736918

Comment: @Mahadevan, you're welcome and don't forget to accept this answer.

Comment: sure definitely i am implementing your code in my html file :)

Comment: one small request actually in my original code these checkbox are in hidden once if the radio button click then only this checkbox will come sorry i have not mentioned in the question that is the reason i have ignore: "input[type='text']:hidden,input[type='checkbox']:hidden",

Comment: @Mahadevan, you' don't need to add `ignore: "input[type='text']:hidden,input[type='checkbox']:hidden"` since all hidden elements are already being ignore.  Otherwise, I've fully answered the question as you presented it to us; and I am not clear on this new request of yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95263/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-sparky).

Answer (score 1):

```
function onClickCall()
{ 
 var checkedItem = 0;
 $('form input.chk_Field_hlt').each(function()
 {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') )
      checkedItem++;
 });

 if(checkedItem > 0)
 {
    // do your work here
 }
 else
 {
     //show error msg
 }
}

onClickCall();
```

Comment: where i can do the validation here :(

Comment: can you please update in the field if it is possible

Comment: The OP is using the jQuery Validate plugin, so there is no need for him to write a custom validator function to do this.