# How to validate a decimal value input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Currently working on only decimal values where in the text field user enter only deciaml value. Should accept only 10 numbers for example if user enter 12345.000000 it should get an alert says **Number field format error. Please re-enter using the proper format.  (6.3)**

With my current jquery code it will accept decimal value

```
$("#txtQty").keyup(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.val($this.val().replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));        
});
```

This is my html code for the text box with this html it will allow only 10 character

```
<input id="txtQty" type="text" maxlength="10"/>
```

I tired the below SO user told but still I am getting the same issue

```
   $('#txtQty').focusout(function(e) {
   if('123456.789'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/) !== null){
      alert("Number field format error. Please re-enter using the proper format. (6.3)");  
   }else{
       '123456.7890'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/) !== null
   }
});
```

before decimal point it has to accept (1-6) 6 number after decimal point it has to accept 3 only zero's if wrongly typed it should throw an alert not at all working still not getting that

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/bq4dh4f8/) for the same

123456.000 --  true 
12345.000 --  true 
1234.000 --  true 
123.000 --  true 
12.000 --  true 
1.000 --  true

Thanks in advance

```
$('.ipt_Havg').focusout(function (e) {
var regexp = /\d*\.\d{3}/
if (document.getElementById("ipt_Havg").value !== regexp) {
    alert("Number field format error. Please re-enter using the proper format. (6.3)");
} else {
    alert('nothing wrong here');
}
});
```

Comment: Surely you realize you've hard coded `'123456.789'` so it does not matter what value you enter into the box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can specify repetitions in RegExps:

```
'123456.789'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/) !== null
true
'123456.7890'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/) !== null
false
```

Comment: is that possible to customize the reg exp with alert

Comment: Well - you can just put the `... !== null` in an if block: `if(... != null) alert('foo')`

Comment: $('#txtQty').keypress(function(e){
    if('123456.789'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/) !== null){
    alert("Kindly enter number only");  
    }else{
     '123456.7890'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/) !== null
    }
});

this was not working as expected if i started type in the text field i am getting the alert message

Answer (score 3):

**1)  Your if/else is broken...**

```
if('123456.789'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/) !== null){
   alert("Number field format error. Please re-enter using the proper format. (6.3)");  
}else{
   '123456.7890'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/) !== null // <- comparison makes no sense here
}
```

You are incorrectly using a comparison operator in place of a "statement" within the `else`.  **The `else` needs to contain a "statement" (something to do) not another comparison operator.**

See:  [MDN "if...else" documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

*If some condition is true then do something, otherwise do something else.*

```
if ('123456.789'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/) !== null) {
   alert("Number field format error. Please re-enter using the proper format. (6.3)");  
} else {
   alert('nothing wrong here');
}
```

---

**2) NOTE**:  I previously thought this was too obvious to even mention, however, you've hard coded `'123456.789'` into the conditional.  In other words, it will never matter what value gets entered into your form...

**`'123456.789'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/)` is always going to be `true` since `'123456.789'` is the only value being used here.**

Otherwise, use the value of the field...

```
$('#ipt_Havg').val().match(/\d*\.\d{3}/) !== null
```

---

**3) Your logic was also backwards.**

```
if ($('#ipt_Havg').val().match(/\d*\.\d{3}/) !== null) {
    alert('nothing wrong here');
} else {
    alert("Number field format error. Please re-enter using the proper format. (6.3)");
}
```

<s>**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/wfzv0h5y/**</s>

---

**4) Incorrect regex...**

> but one small mistake in the end it has to accept only three zero not more than tht but now if i enter 1234.0000 still it was accepting

Your regex also needed fixing...

```
^\d{1,6}\.0{3}$
```

---

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/wfzv0h5y/6/**

Comment: once again thanks @Sparky 

actually i am trying  like this


$('.ipt_Havg').focusout(function(e) {
                                 if ('123456.789'.match(/^[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$/) !== null) {
            alert("Number field format error. Please re-enter using the proper format. (6.3)");  
         } else {
            alert('nothing wrong here');
         }
        });

each and every time Number field format error. Please re-enter using the proper format. (6.3) even after entering the correct format

Comment: @Mahadevan, then your comparison operator is flawed and broken... it's apparently never equal to `null`.  Focus your efforts on that part.

Comment: Hi @Sparky i have updated the fiddle link kindly please check

Comment: @Mahadevan, surely you realize you've hard coded `'123456.789'` so it does not matter what value you enter into the box.

Comment: but one small mistake in the end it has to accept only three zero not more than  tht but now if i enter 1234.0000 still it was accepting :(

Comment: i have looked into regexr.com i found the correct reg exp but still if i enter after decimal more than three zeros it was accepting :(

here is the latest fiddle <br/>http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/wfzv0h5y/2/

Comment: @Mahadevan, your regex is still not correct.  See my updated answer with latest jsFiddle.

Comment: thanks for the help but  if i enter 12.000 it should accept as correct value if you saw my updated question

Comment: hi @Sparky thanks for the help (/^\d{1,6}\.\d{3}$/) this was solved my issue thank you so much if you have time can you please look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716814/group-of-check-box-and-one-hidden-text-field-jquery-validation-not-working-for-g/33741314#33741314

Comment: this was the final reg exp ^\d{1,6}\.0{3}$ thanks for the support

Comment: @Mahadevan, I updated my answer to match your regex.  The answer you accepted contains nothing about fixing all the other critical mistakes you made.  Mine completely fixed your code leaving only the regex for you.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Number Formatter Plugin is a good alternative in your situation.

https://github.com/andrewgp/jsNumberFormatter

You can check your input through this and validate the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML5 input number:

```
<input type='number' step='0.001' max="999999.999" />
```

The `step=` sets the decimal places, the `max=` guarantees the other side.

Comment: If i use html5 how i can pop out alert message

Comment: You don't have to, modern browser do this for you. And if you need to support older browsers, you can always use polyfills. http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number